# How to initialize a string array in ONE go AFTER declaration? C#

Tags: c#, arrays, string

**How can I initialize an array of strings in ONE go AFTER I declare it, not at that moment.**

Example of what I don't want because I am aware you can do it like this:

```
string[] array = new string[2]; // creates array of length 2, default values
string[] array = new string[] { "A", "B" }; // creates populated array of length 2
string[] array = { "A" , "B" }; // creates populated array of length 2
```

Nor do I want it like this, because on a very long array, it would be very tedious:

```
array[0] = "a";
array[1] = "b";
```

I want to declare it first:

```
string[] array = new string[2];
```

Then I want some code to happen:

```
Console.WriteLine("The array has been made, time to fill it up");
```

And finally fill that array up, I've already tried the following ways but none of them work:

```
array { "a","b"};
array[] { "a","b"};
array = {"a","b"};
array[] = { "a", "b" };
```

Thank you ahead of time.

Comment: `string[] array;`  ........................ `array = new [] { "A", "B" };`

Comment: @PatrickArtner Yes that also worked, thank you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can break declaration and initialization like:

```
string[] array;
Console.WriteLine("The array has been made, time to fill it up");
array = new[] {"a","b"};
```

Answer (score 3):

That's not how arrays really work, when you create one you have to populate it OR re-create one and override the old value, so what you want is kind of not possible, at least not with arrays.

What you can do is either use a `List` and `AddRange` or use what Patrick Artner suggested in the comment below your post.

Comment: I see what you mean, great input.